# Swift: How to add items to an array using a UISwitch?

Tags: arrays, swift, uiswitch

I've created a table that has cells with text on the left and a UISwitch on the right. The table is linked to an array with about 70 different strings (and therefore has 70 cells in this table). I have also created an empty array that I want to store strings in. My question is: how do I add strings to the empty array using the UISwitch? I can't seem to figure out how to reference the cells in my table and add whatever text is inside the cell to my empty array only using the UISwitch.

'''
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    let utilities = Utilities()

    return utilities.allFactions.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let utilities = Utilities()

    // Writes a new faction on every line of the table
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = utilities.allFactions[indexPath.row]

    // Creates a switch that can be toggle "on" or "off"
    let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    mySwitch.isOn = false
    // Adds the switch to the right side of the cell
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch

    return cell

}
```

'''

Comment: Can you include codes on how you populating these cells? And are you using the switch to basically append/remove strings from the new array?

Comment: I included the code in the edited post (but not sure why it cut off the first part of it). And yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to append/remove strings to the new array using the strings that are in the array already created.

Comment: First of all - You are creating two instances of Utilities. I'd say take them out and put it in the class level for easier access. Second, I'd say to add a tag to each switch with the indexpath.row as the value. That way, on your @objc method you can get the cell that is being interacted and append it.

Comment: I fixed the first part, but I'm no quite sure what you mean by the second part (I recently started programming).

Comment: Oh sorry - So just do mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row (assuming you will only have 1 section). And, on the didChangeSwitch method, make sure you pass sender: UISwitch as the argument, and check the sender's tag. Now since the value of the tag is an indexpath.row, so just access it by utilities.allfactions[mySwitch.tag] and you should get the value of the string to be appended.

Comment: So I put the mySwitch.tag in the cellForRowAt function but I'm not able to access it in the didChangeSwitch function. Should I put the mySwitch.tag somewhere else?

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer to your problem - hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you starting it. You should do some more checking like if the string exist on the new array or not.

```
// This is your datasource, your array that provides data to the tableview.
let stringSource = ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4"]

// Initialise a new string array
var newStringArray = Array<String>()
```

Below is the normal datasource method for the tableview

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stringSource.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = stringSource[indexPath.row]

        let mySwitch = UISwitch()
// Assign the index row of the cell to the tag - this ensure that the switch has a unique value to it (an ID if you may).
        mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        mySwitch.isOn = false
        cell.accessoryView = mySwitch

        return cell
    }
```

and the selector method:

```
    @objc func didChangeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
// Since we know where the switch comes from (via the tag property) we can 
// simply access the value and append it to our new one
        newStringArray.append(stringSource[sender.tag])
        print(newStringArray)

    }
```

Comment: Glad it works! If it solved your problem - please don't forget to make this answer as correct so that others in the future can also find this solution.

Comment: Sure! I'm also new to this site. How do I do that?

Comment: Just tick the up arrow beside this solution